# Can I build a license or time limited demo version of a stand-alone application using MATLAB Compiler?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, web-applications

I have developed a stand-alone application using the MATLAB Compiler and I would like to be able to distribute it, as this is a common practice to let the potential user tests the application before buying.

Is there any ability to do so using MATLAB?

Your help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `deploytool`? You can create an exe from matlab code that runs with a license free MCR, matlab runtime environment

Comment: Dear Trogdor,
Thank thank you for your comment. In deed, I already have built the project using the Application Compiler, what I'm looking for is how can I let the user use my application for limited time (say one month). I don't know if I can do it using  'deploytool' tool.

Comment: So what is the problem? If you have a .exe file, you can give it to them with the  [matlab runtime library](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) and they can run it.